# bash function "command not found"

Tags: bash, function

I've created a function to check for the existence of a file on a remote server, but I'm getting the error "ssh: command not found" when I try to call the function. Here's the function:

```
remote_file_exists() {
    local SERVER="$1"
    local PATH="$2"
    local FILE="$3"
    FILE_EXISTS=`ssh "$SERVER" \'find "$PATH" -name \"$FILE\"\'`
    if [ -z $FILE_EXISTS ]; then
        return 1
    else
        return 0
    fi
}
```

I'm calling the function like this:

```
if ( remote_file_exists $REMOTE_SERVER "$REMOTE_PATH/" $REMOTE_FILE ); then
    echo "$REMOTE_PATH/$REMOTE_FILE exists on $REMOTE_SERVER"
...
```

The error I'm getting:

```
myscript.sh: line x: ssh: command not found
```

The value of 'x' in the error is the line number of the line in the function that starts with "FILE_EXISTS=".

I suspect this has something to do with not quoting correctly, but I can't figure it out. What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT:** Thanks to Cfreak for the good catch on the PATH variable name. Once I fixed that I got a different error:

```
bash: find <MYPATH> -name "<FILE>": No such file or directory
```

After some experimenting I found that removing the escaped single quotes fixed the 2nd issue. The working line looks like this:

```
FILE_EXISTS=$(ssh "$SERVER" find "$MYPATH" -name \""$FILE"\")
```

Comment: Have you tried using the full path i.e. /usr/bin/ssh ?

Comment: Unrelated to the question, but you should put `$FILE_EXISTS` in doublequotes, since it's likely to contain spaces.

Comment: Unrelated too, but use `$(ssh ...)` instead of the backquotes. It is much safer and nestable...

Comment: Thanks for those suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.  (I've switched the _ to - for easier typing, and `` to $(), but that's not required)

```
remote-file-exists () 
{ 
    local SERVER="$1"
    local MYPATH="$2"
    local FILE="$3"
    local FILE_EXISTS="$(ssh "$SERVER" find "'$MYPATH'" -name "'$FILE'" -print)"
    if [ -z "$FILE_EXISTS" ]; then
        return 1
    else
        return 0
    fi
}
```

You could shorten this substantially.  Also, local variables are usually lowercased to avoid implying that they're environment variables:

```
remote-file-exists () 
{ 
    local server="$1" mypath="$2" file="$3"
    [ ! -z "$(ssh "$server" find "'$mypath'" -name "'$file'" -print)" ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I really like the shortened version.

Answer (score 1):

`PATH` is the variable that controls where bash finds commands and you're resetting it. Change your `PATH` variable name.

```
remote_file_exists() {
    local SERVER="$1"
    local MYPATH="$2"
    local FILE="$3"
    FILE_EXISTS=`ssh "$SERVER" \'find "$MYPATH" -name \"$FILE\"\'`
    if [ -z $FILE_EXISTS ]; then
        return 1
    else
        return 0
    fi
}
```

Comment: Agreed, that was a great catch. Now I get a different error: "bash: find <MYPATH> -name "<FILE>": No such file or directory". I think it's coming from the remote server.

Comment: BTW, I know that MYPATH exists on the remote server, so I'm fairly sure that's not the problem.